# Smooth functions with values in bornological vector space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds, topological-vector-spaces

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or more generally, a manifold) and let $V$ be a separated bornological vector space. Do we have
$$C^\infty(U, V) \cong C^\infty(U) \,\hat{\otimes}\, V,$$
as bornological vector spaces, where $\hat{\otimes}$ denotes the completed bornological tensor product?

Here I did not specify which bornologies to take on $C^\infty(U, V)$ and $C^\infty(U)$; is there a canonical one that makes the above result true?